# Jquery to expand collapse only the div that has been clicked

Tags: jquery, this, parent-child, parent

I have a number of divs on a page that i want to collapse and expand when the user clicks "Expand [+]"

The following code works for one div

```
<h4 class="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">Contact information <span class="expanderSign">Expand [+]</span></h4>
<div id="profile-section" style="overflow:hidden;">
some stuff
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".expanderHead").click(function(){
    if (jQuery(".expanderSign").text() == "Expand [+]")
    {
    jQuery("#profile-section").removeClass("height-min");
    jQuery("#profile-section").addClass("height-auto");
    }
    else
    {
    jQuery("#profile-section").removeClass("height-auto");
    jQuery("#profile-section").addClass("height-min");
    }

    if (jQuery(".expanderSign").text() == "Expand [+]"){
        jQuery(".expanderSign").text("Collapse [-]");
    }
    else {
        jQuery(".expanderSign").text("Expand [+]");
    }


});
});
</script>
```

If i then have a number of divs on the page as such

```
<h4 class="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">Contact information <span class="expanderSign">Expand [+]</span></h4>
<div id="profile-section1" style="overflow:hidden;">
some stuff
</div>

<h4 class="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">Contact information <span class="expanderSign">Expand [+]</span></h4>
<div id="profile-section2" style="overflow:hidden;">
some stuff
</div>

<h4 class="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">Contact information <span class="expanderSign">Expand [+]</span></h4>
<div id="profile-section3" style="overflow:hidden;">
some stuff
</div>

etc....
```

How can i modify my jquery so that it works for all of these divs individually. i.e it will only minimize or maximize the div that has been clicked?

i've tried a number of different combinations using (this) and parent() and child() but i can't seem to get it right.

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. in the end I went for the Accordion - http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Not exactly what i was originally after, but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [context with jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to access the element under current source of event.

**Syntax:** *jQuery( selector [, context ] )*

*Change*

```
jQuery(".expanderSign").text()
```

*To*

```
jQuery(".expanderSign", this).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(this)` to target at the div you clicked.

example:

```
$(".expanderHead").on('click', function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

in this case the div you will click will disappear.

Use `.on()` and not `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it by using toggle and targetting the next div like this:

```
<h4 class="expanderHead">Contact information <span class="expanderSign" style="cursor:pointer;">[+]</span></h4>
<div class="expanderContent">some stuff</div>

$(".expanderContent").hide();
$(".expanderSign").on('click', function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == '[+]' ? '[-]' : '[+]');
    $(this).parent().next("div").toggle();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/USsnz/2/)